# Verification email not being sent to users after registration, but all else is working. (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

All other aspects of verification are working correctly. However, the only thing that isn't working is the actual sending of the email to the new user.

Here is my mailer.

```
namespace App\Mailers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;

class AppMailer {

protected $mailer;

protected $from = 'admin@example.com';

protected $to;

protected $view;

protected $data = [];

public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

public function sendEmailConfirmationTo(User $user)
{
    $this->to = $user->email;
    $this->view = 'emails.confirm';
    $this->data = compact('user');

    $this->deliver();
}

public function deliver()
{
    $this->mailer->send($this->view, $this->data, function($message){
        $message->from($this->from, 'Administrator')
            ->to($this->to);
    });
}
}
```

Here is the method in my registration controller that handles signing up users. The submitSecond() method is where the email is sent.

```
 public function submitSecond(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'family_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'year' => 'min:4|max:4|required',
        'mark' => 'required',
        'course' => 'max:255|required',
        'university_id' => 'required',
        'school' => 'required',
        'exam_id' => 'required',
        // MAKE DESCRIPTION REQUIRED ON DEPLOY 'description' => 'required|min:50' 
    ]);

    $email = Session::get('registration.email');
    $noteID = Session::get('registration.NoteID');

    $user = new User;
    $user->email = $email;      
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->family_name = $request->family_name;
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->year = $request->year;
    $user->mark = $request->mark;
    $user->course = $request->course;
    $user->university_id = $request->university_id;
    $user->school = $request->school;
    $user->exam_id = $request->exam_id;
    $user->save();

    $note=Note::where('id',$noteID)->first();
    $note->user_id=$user->id; 
    $note->exam_id=$user->exam_id;
    $note->save();

    $mailer->sendEmailConfirmationTo($user);

    flash('Thank you for registering. Please verify your email address');

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

I have changed my MAIL_DRIVER to log.

Comment: are you working locally? Have you set up your mail server and tested that you can indeed send mail?

Comment: No, I just thought it would be sent from the email I put down as the $from variable. Silly mistake haha. If I change it to my company email would it work, or is setting this up a whole different story.

Comment: You have to setup your mail server first. The code itself won't do wonders for you, you have to tell your machine how to send the emails. The code is just there to tell your machine to send this request but it's up to your machine how it can handle the email sending. Heck, you can even use other programming language or plain old `mail()` function in php to send emails if your machine is configured correctly. Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail) or even [easier](http://lukepeters.me/blog/getting-the-php-mail-function-to-work-on-ubuntu) HTH.

Comment: If you have set your MAIL_DRIVER to log, it won't ever send the email, but instead save it in ./storage/logs/laravel.log. This is great for development as you don't have to have a mail server setup locally to test/format the actual email.